# Tkinter, doing multiple frames at once, with buttons in each frame. But the buttons ignore the frame they are given and just use the grid

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am writing a Tkinter program where I can make multiple frames that I can choose where they are relative to eachother, so I decided to use grid() to decide which frame does where. I also have a class AppButton that creates a button/label/entry. I am trying to pass in the frame I want the button to be created in, and use a grid to determine its position that is relative to the frame it is created in.

Currently however, the buttons don't get made in the frame I try to pass, but rather it uses the same grid as the frames do, and just gets put there, which looking back makes sense.

My question is, how can I change this so that the button's grid is a separate grid relative only to the frame it is created in? That way if I move the frame around, the buttons will too, but their relative position in the frame stays the same.

Right now the frame and buttons share the same grid and that is how their positions are determined.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFileDialog as tkfd

class AppButton:
    #simple button construction
    #create a button with chosen arguments
    def create_button(self, words, rownum, frame):
        btn = tk.Button(frame, text = words)
        btn.grid(row = rownum, column = 2)

    def create_entry(self, rownum, frame):
        txt = tk.Entry(frame)
        txt.grid(row = rownum, column = 1)

    def create_label(self, words, rownum, frame):
        lbl = tk.Label(frame, text = words)
        lbl.grid(row = rownum, column = 0)

    #input is composed of a Label, an Entry, and a Button. calls the three funcs above
    def create_input(self, words, rownum, frame):
        self.create_label(words, rownum, frame)
        self.create_entry(rownum, frame)
        self.create_button("OK", rownum, frame)

class Application(tk.Frame):
    """A GUI application that creates multiple buttons"""

    #create a class variable from the root(master) called by the constructor
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("The best GUI")
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, width=200, height=200)
        self.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    def new_frame(self, master, color, row, column):
        frame = tk.Frame(master, width=200, height=200, bg=color)
        frame.grid(row = row, column = column)
        return frame


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Button Test Launch")
    app = Application(root)
    appbutton = AppButton()
    frame1 = app.new_frame(root, "red", 3, 1)
    frame2 = app.new_frame(root, "blue", 2, 2)
    appbutton.create_input("test1", 0, root)
    appbutton.create_input("test2", 1, root)
    appbutton.create_input("test3", 2, root)
    appbutton.create_input("test4", 3, root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Here is a picture of what it looks like now:
[Current GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2xMg.png)

My desired end result is to have for example "test1 ______ [OK]" to be completely in a single of those frames.

Comment: Running your code, I get the red background on the last row and the blue background on the second-to-last row. It looks like you changed `root, "red", 0, 1` to `root, "red", 3, 1` and `"blue", 0, 2` to `"blue", 2, 2` during testing, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are telling the buttons to use `root` as their parent. Instead, you should be passing in the frame:

```
appbutton.create_input("test1", 0, frame1)
appbutton.create_input("test2", 1, frame1)
appbutton.create_input("test3", 2, frame2)
appbutton.create_input("test4", 3, frame2)
```